# Getting complete copy of input data using Kafka connect on the sink nodes

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I was trying to write a simple case of using kafka connector. My setup involves using three nodes N1,N2 and N3.
N1 is the source and N2, N3 are the sink nodes in my case.
I am writing data to a text file(say input.txt) on Node N1 and using the standalone kafka connector hope to see a text file with content similar to input.txt on the nodes N2 and N3.

I am using the REST API to make changes in topic name, file name and tasks.max.
However, during the experiments I was unable to get a complete copy of the input.txt on both nodes(N2 and N3) at the same time.

Also tuning the value of tasks.max on nodes (N2 and N3) for the sink connectors decided on which node data would be sent.

So, my question is whether I am wrong in expecting such an outcome?
If so then what should I be expecting as a result of the experiment?
If not then how do I get my desired outcome?

I would appreciate any help in the matter.

Comment: Hi, You question is not so clear. You are telling N1 is a source connector. You should understand that the source connector should push data to Kafka and sink connectors N2 and N3 should get messages from Kafka and push to sinks like (file, database) etc. Why is your N1 writing to a file?

Comment: You should familiarize yourself first with FileStream example in Kafka connector before commenting.
The source connector running on N1 reads from file and pushes data to topic.
The sink  connectors N2 and N3 then subscribe messages from the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually using the same consumer group name for both sinks N2 and N3 and thus data received at the sinks N2 and N3 was divided between them.

Changed the group name ("name") in **connect-file-sink-n2.properties** and **connect-file-sink-n3.properties** that allowed both sinks N2 and N3 to function as independent subscribers and receive complete data.

The below link from the Confluent discussion group supports the explanation:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/confluent-platform/SUn2OmXSAXY